# Is a new instance of service created for each controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am building an angularjs application, that has various controllers. For two of the controllers I am dependency injecting the same service. Is a separate instance of that service created for each of the controllers where it is being injected?

Comment: ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer

**From Docs**

> **Lazily instantiated** – Angular only instantiates a service/factory when
> an application component depends on it.
>
> **Singletons** – Each component
> dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
> generated by the service factory.

Angular `service/factory/provider` are Singleton object. Which create its instance only single time and if you ask for instance again(by injecting dependency) it gives back the old instance which was already created.

You could go throw [**this long answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473) which has everything explained

Comment: Say, I have set a variable "cart" in myservice through  controller1. Now I  have injected myservice in cotroller2. Will I get the value of "cart" set before?

Comment: @SohanShirodkar yes.. that's how factory/service work.. they are singleton object.

Comment: @SohanShirodkar Yes.. see `service/factory/provider/value/constant`, they are just does something with some special meaning.. I don't think so you had went through the linked answer..